# Sometimes, in a Data JPA environment, when three queries occur in one method, one query does not work normally in DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Sometimes, in a Data JPA environment, when three queries occur in one method, one query does not work normally in DB.

```
@Transactional
public void method1(Log log){
        Long userId = log.getUserId();
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new)

        BigDecimal point = BigDecimal.valueOf(100L);
        user.minusPoint(point);
        log.minusPoint(point);
        logRepository.save(new Log(point));
}
```

It works normally for one case.
However, I ran it on several occasions, and one did not work properly.

ex) logList.forEach(log-> a.method1(log));

did not work "log.minusPoint(point);" in all cases.
The data in the DB has not changed about log.
But the new log data was inserted and the user data has been changed.

It was confirmed that the update, insert query was created successfully in the test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable SQL logging and check what data is actually passed to the database.

One of the reason can be: `@Transactional` annotation doesn't work. You need to get a service from the Spring Context to allow Spring to wrap `method1()` with a proxy method to do dirty checking and save data.

`@Transactional` annotation is a bit messy. It is primary not about transactions, but about dirty checking and Hibernate session control.

When you do

```java
logRepository.save(new Log(point));
```

data is saved because `logRepository.save()` has it is own `@Transactional` annotation and does explicit call to save the data.

`log.minusPoint(point)` could work, if `@Transactional` works correctly. A Spring proxy could open Hibernate session (Persistent Context) before `method1()` call and close it in the end. During closing session Hibernate does dirty checking — checks, if any of objects in session were changed and saves such objects.

Another reason can be that you load `log` in a method without `@Transactional` or in a method with own `@Transactional`. Different `@Transactional` means different Persistent Context.
One exception — when `@Transactional` of `method1()` is wrapped with another `@Transactional` that is used for a method that calls `method1()`.

It is bad practice to solve all issues with putting `@Transactional` everywhere. You can just do

```
logRepository.save(log)
```